# I am trying to run following lines of codes

Tags: python-3.x

Can someone help me with what is wrong with this code?

```
fname=input("Enter the name of the file:")
fhandle=open(fname)
word=list()
for line in fhandle:  #All lines starting with "From " are split into list of words
    if not line.startswith("From "):
        continue
        words=line.split()
        word=words[1]            #Second word is obtained
 #Dictionary to count occurence
 counts=dict()
 for name in word:
    counts[name] = counts.get(name,0)+1
     print(counts[name],name)
     print(counts)

#Deciding the maximum occurence of name
maxcount=None
maxword=None
for word,count in counts.items():
    if maxcount is None or count > maxcount:  #if we are ont first word or if 
 the current count is greater than previous maximum count
        maxcount=count
        maxword=word
 print(maxword,maxcount)
```

The output I expected was to print
    OUTPUT:
    cwen@iupui.edu 5
but i end up getting None None as output. Can anybody help me cause I'm stuck from past 4 hrs!

Comment: Can you provide some sample input? What does your input file look like?

Comment: Welcome to SO. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help. You say what the expected and actual outputs are, but you have omitted to give the input (file) that would lead to this output. Also, there are all sorts of problems with your indentation.

Comment: If you outdent lines 8 and 9 to the same as the preceding `if`, you will get some of your debug and output appearing. The `continue` at line 7 ensures they are never going to be executed if they are indented as they are now. Lines 11-15 give you frequencies of the characters in the email address, but not the addresses themselves.

Comment: input file- https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox.txt     @RBalasubramanian

Comment: email addresses don't have space in them so I thought it might work @Nick

Comment: please include a snippet of the input file as a code block in your question's text body, rather than linking externally

Comment: i got my mistake by deindenting the words,split() and adding word.append(words1) it works fine!! Thankyou @Nick  @R Balasubramanian